# Android: SharingActionView on swipe from bottom

Tags: android, android-sharing

I would like to share data with other Apps, but I don't want the standard popup which appears bottom tool bar; I want this kind of view: [image]

I followed the official document: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

So is there a native component to do that in Android SDK? Or is there any library to do that?

thank for your help guys!

Comment: I put the link in my post.

Comment: check the updated answer, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

First create a menu item :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.rashish.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then create a method to show the Intent chooser dialog, like this :

```
private void share() {
    String textToShare = "hello";
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // set the type here i.e, text/image/ etc.
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Then in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, call this function when the menu item is clicked :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. 
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_share) {
        share();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also make sure you've overriden `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your Activity like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here's the **output** :

[screenshot from an android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeDzG.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Android OS Lollipop google has change their share intent design. So to get this design you should have lollipop version and above.

**Update:**

```
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

try like this.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If I follow the official documentation I have previous presentation : https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html#update-menus

Comment: See Updated answer.

Comment: Your code has no effect Sohail. Content indent is not the problem.